# meteor.js using aldeed:tabular with RemoteCollectionDriver

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm encountering an issue when trying to populate data from by collection to the [aldeed:tabular](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular) module for meteor.

My code looks like this and is the root of the project as a common.js file.
All the code below is in a single file:
root/lib/hello.js

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

          database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb");
          idpool = new Mongo.Collection("idpool", {_driver:database});

        Meteor.publish('idpool', function(){
            return idpool.find();
        });

    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.subscribe("idpool");
}


TabularTables = {};

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.idpool = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "idpool",
    collection: idpool,
    columns: [
        {data: "_id", title: "id"}
    ]
});
```

The Tabular code must be in common code any visible to the server and client but when I run the above the "idpool" collection is not defined (out of scope.)

```
Reference Error: idpool is not defined
```

Moving the DB declaration outside the scope to the top of the JS, then  I cant publish and subscribe to it. i.e. :

```
database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://localhost:27017/adaptiveid");
idpool = new Mongo.Collection("idpool", {_driver:database});
//rest of the code.....
```

And if I try to add the a second time by the common Tabular portion of the code like this:

```
idpool = new Mongo.Collection("idpool");
```

I get the following error :

> Error: A method named '/idpool/insert' is already defined

What am I doing wrong here? How do I declare the DB server side and expose it to the common tabular code.

Answer (score 2):

You should place the code inside the /lib folder

```
  /lib
  if(Meteor.isServer){
       database = new        MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://localhost:27017/adaptiveid");
      idpool = new       Mongo.Collection("idpool",   {_driver:database});
      //rest of the code.....
   }
```

Why the isServer and the /lib? Well the /lib folder is the very first meteor loads at the start, but that code is shared between client/server thats why you should specify it to use that code only in the server

**Note** the `Error: A method named 
'/idpool/insert' is already defined` cames here because you are declaring the collection idpool twice.

```
idpool = new Mongo.Collection("idpool", {_driver:database})
```

You already declare the collection there, why are you declaring it twice?, just remove the second `idpoll = new Mongo.Collection('idpool')`

Comment: I only try declare it twice after I encountered the first error...I was getting an error because I am getting a different error before as mentioned above. "ReferenceError: idpool is not defined" because its out of scope at the if(Meteor.isServer) declaration.

Comment: Just put the if(meteor.isServer){dbcodehere} inside the /lib folder, and just declare it 1 time

Comment: The code is already in the lib dir. the original issue is that the TabularTables.idpool = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "idpool",
    collection: idpool,  <---call to idpool here returns that "Reference Error: idpool is not defined".  That is without the duplicate collection declaration

Comment: Did you have a waiton?  On the template? You are trying to acces the database when the databse is not already published/subscribed on the client

Answer (score 0):

I too got stuck, the documentation simply says "Define your table in common code" -- all very true, but equally important is that both the server and client must have access to your collection.

So I found, define all my collections in a single file creating a 'lib/collections.js' to worked well for me, so I knew were they existed and as I refactored I didn't loose track of when they loades, so I would have something like:

```
export const idpoll = new Mongo.Collection('idpool');
export const otherCollection = new Mongo.Colletionc('myOtherCollectin');
```

Then anywhere else in my code that if i needed that collection i just imported it:

```
import { idpoll } from './lib/collections.js'  //ie. path to collections.js
```

In my project I have multiple tables, thus I decided to create a lib/init-tables.js file

```
export let TabularTables = {};
Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables',TabularTables);
```

Then for each table I have a lib/myNameTable.js file along with initial settings.

```
import { TabularTables } from './init-tables.js';  // Import TabularTables helper
import { idpoll } from './collections.js';

TabularTables.Regs = new Tabular.Table({
  name: 'IDPOL',
  collection: idpol,
  columns: [
    {data: 'field', title: 'fieldtitle'},line'},

   ...

  ]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure it's standard practice to declare new collections in the lib folder so they get created before rest of the code runs
Move the idpool line to lib and retry